# Application getting slower and slower when navigating

Tags: windows-phone, dispatchertimer

I'm building a Windows Phone application that does video capture in a page and has a custom player in another page. I'm using my own custom codec so the player needs a lot of `DispatcherTimer` to keep track of several behaviors on the UI part and serve the movie at the good framerate in the codec part.

I'm trying to release all `DispatcherTimer` as I know they are CPU intensive, but even when stopping them my app is still very slow. If I press back-back then follow the flow, the speed divides by two each time. If I don't use my player, eveything is ok. And my player is only made of 3 `DispatcherTimer`, a FileStream and an Image box.

I feel that `DispatcherTimer` are still running in memory and are double-instantiated even if they are instantiated as private on the page directly.

Can I force the page to release all this stuff?

Actually I don't understand yet what is the difference between navigating to a page next to current page, or navigating back. I don't know i.e. how the page is shown again without calling InitializeComponents, so I'm mixed up about which resources to release, and which resources to keep intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My execution speed problem was really caused by some running DispatcherTimer, so I'll answer it to have it archived.

The solution:

1. Ensuring that all `DispatcherTimer` has been instantiated directly on the page so that we can nullify them from anywhere in the code.
2. In OnNavigatedFrom, I kill the `DispatcherTimer` and in `OnNavigatedTo`, I recreate them with myDispatcherX = new DispatcherTimer();
3. No "temporary" timers, like "`DispatcherTimer myTempTimer = new DispatcherTimer;` with `((DispatcherTimer)send).Stop()` in callback, as chances are that it remains in memory in an application where we navigate.

Comment: Need to wait 48h. :) I'm surprised using OnNavigateTo and OnNavigateFrom is so important. I thought it was a workaround, but Microsoft says it's -the- place to handle UI elements states once you navigate somewhere.